# Primefaces picklist has rotated buttons

Tags: primefaces

I'm using the PrimeFaces picklist component, but the "move" buttons (add, addAll, remove, removeAll) have all been rotated by 90 degrees. They should point left and right, not up and down. They work ok; they just don't look right. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or how to correct the problem please?
[image: Rotated buttons on picklist]

I'm using PrimeFaces 8.0; Java 11; Wildfly 21.0.1.
The theme is nova-light, but it's the same with nova-colored and luna-blue. Using theme omega, the button icons are different, but correctly orientated. If I set showSourceControls=true the sort buttons all corrrectly show up and down. It's just the middle buttons that are pointing the wrong way.

The component is defined as:

```
            <p:pickList value="#{postController.tagPicklist}" var="tag" 
                        rendered="#{postController.mode eq 'Add' or postController.mode eq 'Edit' }"
                        itemLabel="#{tag.name}" itemValue="#{tag}" 
                        converter="myTagConverter"
                        >
            </p:pickList>
```

Comment: It might be a bug since fixed because looking at the latest showcase with Nova Light it looks OK: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/pickList.xhtml?jfwid=bfd68

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported to PF and appears to be a problem with the themes CSS.

Issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/6880